# How to remove view in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `View` (`CupsViewController`) with a `Label` and when it's clicked, `TableView` (`AddressTableController`) slides from the bottom of the screen and stays in the lower half. 
In `TableView`, when `Ok Button`is pressed, I want to change value of `Label`and remove `TableView`with animation (that is, slide to the bottom).

Here is my code:

**CupsViewController**

*Method called when click on `Label`*

```
- (IBAction)showPop:(id)sender
{
    addressTableController = [[AddressTableController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [addressTableController setDelegate:self];
    [[self view] addSubview:[addressTableController myTableView]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        [[addressTableController myTableView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, kScreenHeight * 0.5, kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight * 0.5)];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

*Method called from `AddressTableController`when `Button`is pressed*

```
- (void)addressTableController:(AddressTableController *)viewController didChooseValue:(int)value {
    direccionLabel.text = [[[[myAppDelegate usuarioActual] cups] objectAtIndex:value] direccion];
    [addressTableController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Image**

[image]

As you can see, I've tried with `removeFromSuperview`but it does nothing. How can I slide `TableView`to the bottom?

Comment: Do `[addressTableController myTableView]` and `addressTableController.view` return the same object?

Comment: If I do `addressTableController.view`, table appears at the bottom (like I have now) and above the actual view, covering all screen.

Comment: So `addressTableController.myTableView` is not equal to `addressTableController.view`. And what if you try `[[addressTableController myTableView] removeFromSuperview];` instead of `[addressTableController.view removeFromSuperview];`? Because you add the former as a subview, not the latter.

Comment: Are you trying to change the size of the tableview so it covers less of the screen? Or are you trying to move it off the screen entirely and then remove it from the view altogether?  I'm not exactly sure what you are attempting to animate and then what you want the desired effect to be.  I am assuming that you want to animate the view entirely off the screen, and then remove it from the super view so it is no longer retained in the view hierarchy?  Clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: HI, I think, you are creating two different object of addressTableController and try to remove other object instead of added  object..

Comment: @imo: Thanks! It was the problem. If you put it in an Answer, i'll select it as the correct one.

Comment: @AdamG: When I create tableview, I change its size. When it shows, it slides from the bottom of the screen to the middle. Now I can do it disappear, but I would like if I can do it animatedly, it is: slide it from the middle of the screen to the bottom. Is it possible?

Comment: @kokx: Yes, the solution is what imo said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you `myTableView` property returns a different view, not the one that is referenced in the `view` property. So you basically add the former as a subview (`[[self view] addSubview:[addressTableController myTableView]];`), but try to remove the latter (`[addressTableController.view removeFromSuperview];`).

Just do

```
[[addressTableController myTableView] removeFromSuperview];
```

instead of

```
[addressTableController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Here you go. Cheers, mate! :)

---

P.S. 
if you want to animate the view out, you can do it like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    // animation code...
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [[addressTableController myTableView] removeFromSuperview];
}];
```